# In python, how can I print all the values for the same key from different dictionaries on top of one another?

Tags: python, dictionary, output

Let's say I want to output three lines. Each line corresponding to a different table. The columns are the corresponding values to the keys.

This would make the print out vertical:

```
for i in list_of_keys:
    print dict1[i], dict2[i], dict3[i]
```

Any way for me to create a simple way for the dictionary values to be stacked on top of one another instead?

One way to do this would be to write:

```
for i in list_of_keys:
    print dict1[i],
for i in list_of_keys:
    print dict2[i],
```

But the problem here is if the dictionaries contain more values than can fit on one line I get multiple lines for a dictionary until that dictionary runs out and then multiple lines underneath. Versus lining up the dictionaries value for value with the keys defining the columns the values are lined up in.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want the result to be. Do you want the values to be printed until just before the end of line? Or do you want, say, four values per line?

Comment: If the dictionaries contain more values than can fit on a line then I guess if I could set a pre-determined value (like 50 characters) before a new line starts, that would work well for various types of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Python 2, I wrote a function `pprint_multiline` which you can customize wildly.

You can customize the followings:

- the line length
- the separator between items
- the separator between lines (empty string for blank line between two blocks of lines, `None` for no line separator at all)
- the alignment of each item, and
- the alignment character.

The function accepts a list of lists to be printed horizontally, so you'd need to unpack the dictionary before calling this function, as exemplified in the examples I give below.

This works for any value in the dictionaries, assuming it implements `__str__` function (which most Python objects do).

The function:

```
def pprint_multilines(linelen=80, separator=' ', line_separator=None,
                      align='left', align_char=' ', lists=[]):
    maxlen = max(len(lst) for lst in lists)
    printed_lines = ['']*len(lists)
    empty = True
    printed = False
    for i in xrange(maxlen):
        max_item_len = max(len(str(lst[i])) for lst in lists)
        if max_item_len + len(printed_lines[0]) + 1 > linelen:
            if printed and line_separator is not None:
                if len(line_separator) > 0:
                    print line_separator*(linelen/len(line_separator))
                else:
                    print
            for printed_line in printed_lines:
                print printed_line
            printed = True
            printed_lines = ['']*len(lists)
            empty = True
        for lst_idx, lst in enumerate(lists):
            if not empty:
                printed_lines[lst_idx] += separator
            if align == 'left':
                printed_lines[lst_idx] += str(lst[i]).ljust(max_item_len, align_char)
            else: # align == 'right'
                printed_lines[lst_idx] += str(lst[i]).rjust(max_item_len, align_char)
        else:
            empty = False
    if not empty:
        if printed and line_separator is not None:
            if len(line_separator) > 0:
                print line_separator*(linelen/len(line_separator))
            else:
                print
        for printed_line in printed_lines:
            print printed_line
```

To see it in action, you can see the following examples:

```
dict1 = {'a': 'first', 'b': 'second', 'c': 3, 'd': ['the', 'fourth']}
dict2 = {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
dict3 = {'a': '1', 'b':'two', 'c':'three', 'd': 'fourth'}
list_of_keys = ['a','b','c','d']

pprint_multilines(linelen=15, separator=' ', align='left', align_char=' ',
                  line_separator='-',
                  lists=[[dict1[key] for key in list_of_keys],
                         [dict2[key] for key in list_of_keys],
                         [dict3[key] for key in list_of_keys]])
print

pprint_multilines(linelen=15, separator=' ', align='left', align_char=' ',
                  lists=[[dict1[key] for key in list_of_keys],
                         [dict2[key] for key in list_of_keys],
                         [dict3[key] for key in list_of_keys]])
print

pprint_multilines(linelen=25, separator=' ', align='left', align_char=' ',
                  line_separator='',
                  lists=[[dict1[key] for key in list_of_keys],
                         [dict2[key] for key in list_of_keys],
                         [dict3[key] for key in list_of_keys]])
print

pprint_multilines(linelen=45, separator=' ', align='left', align_char='_',
                  lists=[[dict1[key] for key in list_of_keys],
                         [dict2[key] for key in list_of_keys],
                         [dict3[key] for key in list_of_keys]])
print

pprint_multilines(linelen=45, separator=' ', align='right', align_char=' ',
                  lists=[[dict1[key] for key in list_of_keys],
                         [dict2[key] for key in list_of_keys],
                         [dict3[key] for key in list_of_keys]])
```

which will output (with some comments):

```
first second
1     2
1     two
---------------   <-- This is the line separator
3                 <-- This next item fits in 15 chars, but
3                     if appended to the previous line
three                 this item won't fit, so break the third item to new lines
---------------   <-- Note that this spans the specified line length
['the', 'fourth']
4
fourth

first second
1     2
1     two
3                 <-- No line separator!
3
three
['the', 'fourth']
4
fourth

first second 3     <-- linelen=25, the third item now fits!
1     2      3
1     two    three
                   <-- A blank line separator
['the', 'fourth']
4
fourth

first second 3____ ['the', 'fourth'] <-- Showing alignment chars
1____ 2_____ 3____ 4________________ <-- linelen=45, everything fits!
1____ two___ three fourth___________

first second     3 ['the', 'fourth'] <-- These blocks are right-aligned
    1      2     3                 4
    1    two three            fourth
```